# Use Reflection class to pass exact number of parameters to class constructor PHP

Tags: php, reflection

I am creating my own MVC framework and the way I handle creation of models is as follows:

```
class ModelFactory {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public static function Create($model, $params = array()) {
        if ( ! empty($model)) { 
            $model = ucfirst(strtolower($model));
            $path  = 'application/models/' . $model . '.php';

            if (file_exists($path)) {
                $path           = rtrim(str_replace("/", "\\", $path), '.php');

                $modelConstruct = new \ReflectionMethod($path, '__construct');
                $numParams      = $modelConstruct->getNumberOfParameters();

                //fill up missing holes with null values
                if (count($params) != $numParams) {
                    $tempArray = array_fill(0, $numParams, null);
                    $params    = ($params + $tempArray);
                }


                //instead of thi
                return new $path($params);

               //I want to DO THIS 
               return new $path($param1, $param2, $param3 ... $paramN) 
               //where $paramN is the last value from $params array
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

a simple Model example:

```
   class UsersModel {
        public function __construct($userID, $userName) {
           //values of these parameters should be passed from Create function
           var_dump($userID, $userName);
        }
   }
```

**Solved:**

Thanks to **schokocappucino** & **pozs** I fixed it by doing this:

```
$modelConstruct = new \ReflectionMethod($path, '__construct');
$numParams      = $modelConstruct->getNumberOfParameters();

if (count($params) != $numParams) {
    $tempArray = array_fill(0, $numParams, '');
    $params    = ($params + $tempArray);
}

return (new \ReflectionClass($path))->newInstanceArgs($params);
```

Comment: **1.** Model in MVC is not a class but a layer. User would most likely be a [domain object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) 2. Constructor should require only mandatory parameters. And there is no way that `$userId` can be a mandatory parameter. 3. Why is that method static? Especially since there is a perfectly legitimate constructor there. **4.** Factories are **NOT** autoloaders.

Comment: 1. I want to use Model the way I want in my own framework, thats why Im writing my own. 2. I want it to be generic and dynamic since all constructors will have different parameter lists and instead of doing `$model = new MyModel($param1, $param2)` I want to do `$model = Factory::Create('myModel', array($param1));` and `$param2` is automatically set. 3. It is static so I dont have to create an object of a factory to create object of a model. 4. I'm not autoloading im creating an object of a model. I have autoloaders

Comment: So, basically you think, that MVC stand for "My Very Code".

Comment: no it stands for Model View Controller where I create objects of Models and use Models for database access only and all logic. Controller parses data and gives it to view.

Comment: @GGio you must understand that the MVC pattern is more complex then that. tereško have given you some nice pointers and you should really dig into those as they will help you ALOT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the constructor of a class using reflection, use [`ReflectionClass::getConstructor()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstructor.php).
To create a new instance (with the constructor) using an argument list, use [`ReflectionClass::newInstanceArgs()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.newinstanceargs.php)

Answer (score 2):

`return (new ReflectionClass($path))->newInstanceArgs($params);`